# Why Pentaho community server 6.1 started giving repository reference error while running, scheduling and downloading of random files on console

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

Having been a long-time user of the Pentaho Community Server, I have recently encountered an unprecedented occurrence of repository reference errors. Despite my efforts, I have been unable to pinpoint the root cause of this issue. The problem manifests when attempting to run, schedule, or download/export random files on the Pentaho console using version 6.1 of the community server.

Here are some error snippets in different cases:

**While Running or executing :**

```
Export failed: :home exception while getting data for file with id "d95c6377-337c-4bc0-8e76-a9a434bfe039"
Reference number: b6ddf7a1-3807-43b3-ae78-12a7900e6e37
org.pentaho.platform.api.repository2.unified.UnifiedRepositoryException: exception while getting data for file with id "d95c6377-337c-4bc0-8e76-a9a434bfe039"
Reference number: b6ddf7a1-3807-43b3-ae78-12a7900e6e37
Caused by: org.springframework.extensions.jcr.JcrSystemException: Repository access exception; nested exception is org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.DataStoreException: Record e574c05bf138f32dbfb9a60a82ee7c5e0a8269d6 does not exist
```

**While Downloading or Exporting: **

```
ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.FileResource] Export failed: :home:myfolder:services_response_details.prpt exception while getting data for file with id "c24d3626-0484-4f3a-ba59-e77e9b7e59aa"
Reference number: 7cc31772-73fc-4904-b998-e643b2246c1b
org.pentaho.platform.api.repository2.unified.UnifiedRepositoryException: exception while getting data for file with id "c24d3626-0484-4f3a-ba59-e77e9b7e59aa"
Reference number: 7cc31772-73fc-4904-b998-e643b2246c1b
    at org.pentaho.platform.repository2.unified.ExceptionLoggingDecorator.callLogThrow(ExceptionLoggingDecorator.java:512) ~[pentaho-platform-repository-6.1.0.1-196.jar:6.1.0.1-196.-1]
Caused by: org.springframework.extensions.jcr.JcrSystemException: Repository access exception; nested exception is org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.DataStoreException: Record 18b04e3b2a048599447841e92ad6616a78196e7a does not exist
    at org.springframework.extensions.jcr.SessionFactoryUtils.translateException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:223) ~[se-jcr-0.9.jar:?]
Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.DataStoreException: Record 18b04e3b2a048599447841e92ad6616a78196e7a does not exist
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.AbstractDataStore.getRecord(AbstractDataStore.java:47) ~[jackrabbit-data-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
```

**While Subscribing: **

```
2023-07-19 04:00:10,227 ERROR [org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor] 288348751: Report processing failed.
org.pentaho.platform.api.repository2.unified.UnifiedRepositoryException: exception while creating file with name "Customer details.pdf"
Reference number: 40e104af-a93a-4ca9-bb81-9a50ca9926ef
    at org.pentaho.platform.repository2.unified.ExceptionLoggingDecorator.callLogThrow(ExceptionLoggingDecorator.java:512) ~[pentaho-platform-repository-6.1.0.1-196.jar:6.1.0.1-196.-1]
    
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JCR transaction; nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
    at org.springframework.extensions.jcr.jackrabbit.LocalTransactionManager.doCommit(LocalTransactionManager.java:192) ~[se-jcr-0.9.jar:?]
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.data.core.TransactionException: Unable to prepare transaction.
Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.StaleItemStateException: 87f09273-00e5-4a97-aa66-0a9db9307364 has been modified externally
Caused by: javax.jcr.ItemExistsException: This node already exists: /pentaho/tenant0/home/subscription/Customer details.pdf
2023-07-20 04:00:13,323 ERROR [org.pentaho.reporting.platform.plugin.SimpleReportingAction] [execute] Component execution failed.
org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportProcessingException: Failed to process the report
Caused by: org.pentaho.platform.api.repository2.unified.UnifiedRepositoryException: exception while creating file with name "Customer details(2).pdf"
Reference number: 6e8d4232-19fe-4060-bb93-a2b14c734b9e
```

Whenever these errors occur, the reports fail to execute and subscribe as intended. Despite attempting to resolve the problem by restarting the server or machine, the error remains persistent.

One potential solution I discovered is to redeploy the affected file to the server, which temporarily resolves the issue. However, relying on this approach becomes impractical as it necessitates repeated redeployment, which is not an ideal long-term solution.

To ensure a more permanent fix, I am determined to identify the root cause of these recurring issues and implement a robust solution to prevent the errors from reoccurring.